# Adding an image inside the input type text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show the password using an eye icon for certain time. I tried to add class and added the background image for that input.But the height and width is aligned bigger than the text box.On trying to change the height, the input size reduced as the background img is inside the input.

Is there any way to resolve this?

```js
$("#ShowCurrentPassword").click(function(){
$('#Password').attr('type', 'text'); 
setTimeout(function(){$('#Password').attr('type', 'password'); }, 900);
});
```

```css
input{
 background: url("eye.png") no-repeat fixed;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="form-group">
     <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Current Password</label>
     <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder=""></div>
     <div class="col-sm-1"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" id="ShowCurrentPassword"></i></div>
                                         
</div>
```

P.s: I tried with boostrap glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" id="ShowCurrentPassword and it s working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use background-size for height and width , check my edits

```js
$("#ShowCurrentPassword").click(function(){
$('#Password').attr('type', 'text'); 
setTimeout(function(){$('#Password').attr('type', 'password'); }, 900);
});
```

```css
input{
background: url(https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/7467-200.png) no-repeat;
background-size: 25px;
background-position: 2%;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Current Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7"><input type="password" class="form-control" id="Password" placeholder=""></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" id="ShowCurrentPassword"></i></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you,Its working :) But on  typing the password the eye icon should not be there..!

Comment: @HemaNandagopal  how's it's working. are you able to click on eye icon? Because i am not

Comment: I just used the classes,Did you import the jquery plugin?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that you have problems with jquery I thought the problem is on style only, If you want a clickable eye it can't be as background why not as a button (show) , I can update my code if you make your decision !.

Comment: I already tried the show button and it is working fine.I was trying to explore my UI with different styles and thought of using eye.NO worries, I used that with that eye icon on the left side. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap input-group classes

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
</div>
```

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_input_groups.htm](http://input%20group)